# Deixar a pesquisa do autocomplete em negrito

Tags: jquery, autocompletar

Tenho esse script de busca:

```js
   $( function($) {
    $( "#p" ).autocomplete({
     source: "php/search_palavras.php?id_cidade=<?php echo $id_cidade; ?>",
     minLength: 2,
         
     select: function( event, ui ) {
      // Set autocomplete element to display the label
      this.value = ui.item.label;
        
      // Store value in hidden field
      $('#hidden_p').val(ui.item.id);

      // Prevent default behaviour
      return false;     
     }
    });
       
    $( "#p" ).click(function() {
     $('#hidden_p').val(0);
     $('#p').val('');
    });   
   });
```

Procurei várias formas de fazer isso, mas não consegui.
Como faço para que eu procurar algo, a procura fique em negrito.

Por exemplo:

pada

**pada**ria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o método [._renderItem](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-_renderItem) e capturar o texto digitado, fazer um `replace` no retorno adicionando por exemplo a tag `strong`, exemplo:

```js
$( function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags,
     
    })
    $.ui.autocomplete.prototype._renderItem = function (ul, item) {        
        var t = String(item.value).replace(
                new RegExp(this.term, "gi"),
                "<strong>$&</strong>");
        return $("<li></li>")
            .data("item.autocomplete", item)
            .append("<a>" + t + "</a>")
            .appendTo(ul);
    };
    });
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags" placeholder="Digite Java">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer o seguinte:
Pegar a parte já digitada e deixar em negrito com

```
document.write("<p>Bold: " + txt.bold() + "</p>");
```

e completar o resto com a parte vinda do auto complete, mas caso o auto complete já traga uma String com a palava inteira é só dividir ela comparando com o que já foi digitado.

[FONTE](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_bold.asp)

Comment: Desculpe por não colocado antes:
O que estou procurando seria algo nisso:

https://www.tudoaquicampinas.com.br/campinas-sp